# views and kviews: What's the difference?

Tags: support

What is "kviews"?  See the attached screen capture.

[image]

Comment: Move the mouse over the kviews  to get the exact number.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

'k' stands for 'kilo', i.e. 1000. So 2 kviews are (about) 2000 views, while 57 views are really just 57 views.